# WPF Two-way databinding question

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So I am trying to programmatically create Two-Way bindings for dynamically generated tabs, and the Path requirement is giving me trouble.

*edit* When I do not use two-way binding and remove the path/source/mode/trigger it works correctly

Here is the binding I am using:

```
Binding schedBind = new Binding();
schedData = Converter.GetTemplate(false);
schedGrid.DataContext = schedData;
schedBind.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGrid.DataContextProperty);
schedBind.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
schedBind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
schedBind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
schedGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, schedBind);
```

However when I create an instance of the tab that uses the `DataGrid schedGrid` it shows up blank. The `DataTable schedData` does have information in it, so why isn't the binding filling the `DataGrid`?

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a class `DataHolder` which had a `SchedData` property. I then set the instance of the `DataHolder` to the `DataContext` and set the `Path=SchedData`.

Not exactly what I had hoped for but it works.